# Error when extracting titles from a web page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract titles of the news from a web page and I ran into an AttributeError when I ran the code. Could you please help me figure out how to extract the titles?

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://news.ycombinator.com")
print(r.text)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html5lib")
print(soup.get_text())

summaries = soup.find_all("tr", class_="athing") 
summaries[0]
```

I tried the following line and I was able to extract the title, but the date always tags along. (for example: 'Tweetbot. April 2011 – January 2023 (tapbots.com)') **Could you please help me extract only the titles?**

```
summaries[0].find("span", class_="titleline").get_text().strip()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In this modified code, I get the text inside the anchor HTML element contained *inside* the `span` HTML element - which is the element that has the title.

Here's the code:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://news.ycombinator.com")
print(r.text)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html5lib")
print(soup.get_text())

summaries = soup.find_all("tr", class_="athing") 
summaries[0] 

titles = []
for indx, summary in enumerate(summaries):
  # Add to the list of titles the text found on the element found.
  titles.append(summary.find("span", class_="titleline").find("a").get_text("", strip=True))

# Print the titles obtained: 
print(titles)
```

Result:

```
['Tweetbot. April 2011 – January 2023',
 'NRC Certifies First U.S. Small Modular Reactor Design',
 'GitHub Sunsetting Subversion Support',
 'From Zero to main(): Bare metal C',
 'Large Transformer Model Inference Optimization',
 'Towards a Reproducible F-Droid',
 'Bitmovin (YC S15) Is Hiring a Solutions Engineer US',
 'Job Hunting in 2022',
 'Citizen scientists report global rapid reductions in the visibility of stars',
 'Idris: A language for type-driven development',
 'There was PayPal mafia. Meet the Berkeley mafia',
 'Show HN: Timeretain – Track, visualize, and export your hours',
 'The exploited labor behind artificial intelligence (2022)',
 'Lean – Theorem Prover',
 'Writing a Vector Tileserver for Osm2streets',
 'ChatGPT is not all you need. A SOTA Review of large Generative AI models',
 'Pipe Operator (|>) For JavaScript',
 'Palindromic Rolling Hash (2016)',
 'The Rise of Steel Part II',
 'Elder Mother',
 'Elizabeth Holmes bought one-way ticket to Mexico after convicted of fraud',
 'Script Kit: cross-platform, scriptable, automatic shortcuts to everything',
 'General technology for enabling AI capabilities with LLMs and Generative models',
 'How the Discovery of a Unique Sign Language Reconnected a Linguist with Her Past',
 'Runlike: Given an existing Docker container, prints the command line to run it',
 'PyTorch Vulkan Back End User Workflow',
 'Can a Human See a Single Photon? (1996)',
 'Practical Scheme',
 'Mercedes-Benz workforce to receive record profit-sharing bonus',
 'Google to reduce workforce by 12k']
```

N.B. the first title contains the text "*January 2023*" - not sure if you want to remove this text as well.

Comment: Your solution is exactly what I wanted! Thank you.